# Angular material 7 use grid with drag and drop

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, grid

I try to make a mix between this
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#reordering-lists

and this
https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview

But impossible !

I try to do something like

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div *ngFor="let book of books" cdkDrag>
    <mat-grid-tile class="example-box">{{ book }}</mat-grid-tile>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the drop doesn't work.

To be clear, I try to do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoLqw.png), with "1", "2", "3", "4" interchangeable by drag&drop **with Angular material**

Did anyone ever manage to do something like that?

Comment: It does work, but it doesn't work very well. I suspect it has to do with MatGridList and the way that it is dynamically laid out.

Comment: @Goeffrey have you gotten any further?

Comment: cant you just solve this with flexbox and in a css fashion? Thats means that you horizontal 1x4 list breaks into 2x2 matix?

Comment: I've spent the whole day trying to achieve the same thing without success. Then I read the material drag&drop documentation and it looks like we are supposed to make only vertical or horizontal lists -->  List orientation: The cdkDropList directive assumes that lists are vertical by default. This can be changed by setting the orientation property to `"horizontal".

Comment: Well, it won't work nicely when moved down the grid now. As per the documentation there's either horizontal or vertical and no grid approach :- |

Comment: https://kreuzerk.github.io/ng-sortgrid/

Comment: @suhailvs this does not seem to work at all with Angular 10

Answer (score 20):

**This is a workaround** -We can use a `cdkDropListGroup` and create two `cdkDropList` where one would act like placeholder and using `cdkDropListEnterPredicate` we can allow user to move the item horizontally simultaneously update the Dom manually to display the placeholder. and when user drops the item we have to manually update the dom and move item into array.

This guy created a work around using `flex-wrap`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuiviw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

For Angular Material version 7.3.7 and above -
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyz1eb

Comment: only problem is that, I couldn't make it work in angular 8

Comment: Agreed, does not work in Angular 10 either, likely for same reasons.

Comment: this should work in with angular version 8 and above -  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyz1eb

Comment: Which version? Can you create a stackblitz and i will help you.

Comment: Does not work anymore. Requires slight improvements. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63979423/1177597

Comment: I couldn't make it work in Angular 11. @indrajeet, will u please help me to resolve this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-card

Comment: Thanks @ViacheslavDobromyslov, that solved the issue for Angular 10.

Comment: `Property 'enter' does not exist on type 'CdkDropList<any>'` does thos still work for cdk 12?

Answer (score 7):

In case of someone interested how to do version from @ndrajeet's answer for Angular 12 - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hhqtt3?file=src/app/app.component.ts .

Working with Angular for 2-3 weeks only, so almost sure there is plenty to improve. But at least it's working :)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="l1" class="example-list"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <mat-grid-tile cdkDrag *ngFor="let tile of tiles" [colspan]="tile.cols" [rowspan]="tile.rows"
            [style.background]="tile.color">
            {{tile.text}}
          </mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
```

it worked for me

Comment: `[cdkDropListData]="l1"` where `l1` is coming from?

Comment: its just an array name