# CdkDropList enter deprecated not exists in CdkDropList

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

After doing the update to Angular Material 10 I got a problem with drag&drop directive. `enter`, in `cdkDropList` doesn't exists anymore and so my code

```
this.placeholder.enter(drag, drag.element.nativeElement.offsetLeft, drag.element.nativeElement.offsetTop);
```

not working. I tried to find out a solution but without success. That's an example with the deprecated `enter` function https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dragdrop-grid-pnyded
can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks a lot

Comment: This apparently is now handled in `DragListRef`. Have a look at this: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19059

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the correct way.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please help out and post it here

Answer (score 36):

I had the same problem, and fixed it with:

```
this.placeholder._dropListRef.enter(drag._dragRef, 
drag.element.nativeElement.offsetLeft, drag.element.nativeElement.offsetTop);
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer, as it solves this issue for Angular 10.

Comment: This also solves the issue for Angular 11

Comment: angular 13 too. anything above the deprecated version i assume.