# Angular [CDK v10+] cant find a proper replacement for "enter" deprecated function in drag and drop CDK

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I was mistakenly worked on an angular version older then 10 in stackblitz (some sort of a code-pane).

here I found the moved the function enter [github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19059).
but it didn't helped at my case.
on a grid based drag and drop, that have the capability to drag between different draggable-containers. forked from [angular dragdrop grid](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dragdrop-grid).
The only error that pooped when I upgrade to the latest version (12.1.2) is here

```
this.placeholder.enter(
  drag,
  drag.element.nativeElement.offsetLeft,
  drag.element.nativeElement.offsetTop
);
```

error: `Property 'enter' does not exist on type 'CdkDropList<any>'`

the only reference I found is this page from [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169673/cdkdroplist-enter-deprecated-not-exists-in-cdkdroplist).
when I try the solution the behaviour is messed-up and the console is logging this error `ncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

currently [this is the state](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dragdrop-grid-jwtx2m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

I wish to transfer this functionality to the latest CDK version without losing the functionality.

when i switch back and forth between version i notice that the behavior of `cdkDropListEnterPredicate` is not working as its use to.

in v9 `cdkDropListEnterPredicate` is calling the functions every pixel but for v 12 the behavior has changed.

to see the error in action go to the `package.json` and change the from `"@angular/cdk": "9.1.2"`
to: `"@angular/cdk": "12.1.2"`
I have tried to use `dragRef` and `dropListRef` but failed.

Answer (score 3):

Please  Click for sample example...... [here] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-drag-drop-sortable-flex-wrap-if3hjb?file=src/app/app.component.html)

now with the new version we can replace all the previous method with single one(cdkDragEntered) and it will take care of all things.

Comment: This needs to be accepted as the answer.  It is a far better algorithm than `cdkDropListEnterPredicate` and works out-of-the-box in Angular 12.