# Maximum call stack size exceeded when trying to implement Angular Drag and Drop grid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm trying to implement the same dragable grid as here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dragdrop-grid-pnyded.
I faced a number of problems: 
First one was that `CdkDropList enter()` was deprecated, so i found solution here:  [CdkDropList enter deprecated not exists in CdkDropList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169673/cdkdroplist-enter-deprecated-not-exists-in-cdkdroplist). 
But when I'm trying to drag elements, console gives me a bag of errors:
***Maximum call stack size exceeded***
at this line: 
`this.placeholder._dropListRef.enter(drag._dragRef, drag.element.nativeElement.offsetLeft, drag.element.nativeElement.offsetTop);`,

also: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_getSiblingContainerFromPosition') at DragRef._updateActiveDropContainer (drag-drop.mjs:959:51)`

and
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') at Object.next (drag-drop.mjs:3584:64)`

I tried to find a solution, but to no avail.
Can anyone help me? Thank in advance!